# Is 言っちゃうんですね similar to よく言えますね in this example?

Tags: translation, word-choice, meaning

Could someone help me with this sentence?

> 自分で可愛いとか**言っちゃうんですね**。

Is it similar to **よく言えますね**?

Answer (score 2):

They are more or less similar, but ～とか言っちゃうんですね can be a friendly response depending on the context, while よく言えますね ("How dare you say...") tends to sound more accusatory and offensive. When you say the former with an appropriate tone, probably it can sound like "Wow you're such a confident girl!"